# Make does not follow the dependencies chain

Tags: makefile

I have this Makefile:

```
all: src/exec

src/exec:
    make -C src/

src/exec: src/bar.o
src/bar.o: src/bar.h
```

And in the `src` directory these files:

```
touch src/exec src/bar.o src/bar.h
```

When I hit make I get:

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Now, if I make a change to `src/bar.h`, I get the same:

```
$ touch src/bar.h
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

I don't understand it. Make should follow the dependencies chain:

```
all <- src/exec <- src/bar.o <- src/bar.h
```

If `src/bar.h` changes the target as to be rebuilt right?

When I am using `*.d` files generated by either `gcc -MM` or `makedepend`, I notice exactly the same rules in these files:

```
bar.o: bar.c bar.h
exec: bar.o foo.o
```

So what I am trying to do should work at some point. Am I wrong?

Comment: Since `src/exec` exists, there's nothing for `make` to do (the modification time of `src/bar.o` is almost certainly the same as the modification time of `src/exec`).  Cancelling all the suffixes is also probably not a good idea; it effectively removes all the useful default rules.  You should not include the `.SUFFIXES:` line unless you (a) know for sure what it does and (b) reset the suffixes to something non-empty — or write the makefile in a wholly different style.

Comment: So how does `makedepend` works? It does exactly the same creating rules like `bar.o: bar.c bar.h` and `exec: bar.o`

Comment: Do you mean `makedepend` or `make depend`?  The former is a separate program, only marginally related to your makefile — you'd need to identify where it comes from so it can be studied.  The latter requires a rule in your makefile which you haven't shown.  (And it doesn't mess with `.SUFFIXES:` for one thing.)

Comment: I am talking about `makedepend` of `gcc -MM` (the `.SUFFIXES` is just that I don't want make do something in my back, especially in this situation where I am trying to understand what `make` is doing).

Comment: The '`makedepend` of `gcc -MM`' is meaningless to me.  Please update your question to illustrate what you're discussing.  Note that there is no file such as `bar.c` discussed/mentioned in your question, and there is no default rule to build a `.o` file from a `.h` file ordinarily — even before you tamper with `.SUFFIXES`.  You want `make` to behave sanely.  Since you don't understand what `.SUFFIXES` does, don't tinker with it.  Doing so breaks your makefile.

Comment: What makes you say that I do not understand what `.SUFFIXES` does?

Comment: OK; you understand what `.SUFFIXES` does. That's fine. I don't think you would be asking this question, though, if you understood what it does. I think it is a factor (not the only factor) in your confusion. But feel free to ignore me — you'll have to wait for more input from someone else. (There's also an outside chance that the line appearing at the end of the `makefile` means it doesn't affect you. But that too suggests misunderstanding of its purpose.) If you want to convince me you understand it, you could outline what you think that line does, and why that is beneficial to your makefile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82362/discussion-between-nowox-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: It would be much simpler to make your "project" using a Makefile present in the `src` path. But, I understand your intention is to really build it from an upper directory. Am i right?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca You're right but this is not my question. In fact I have another `Makefile` into `src` but I don't want to blindy execute `make -C src/` from the parent Makefile. So I would like to use dependencies to determine whether or not I need to rebuild my `src/*` target.

Comment: It's strange that you have 2 targets named the same: `src/exec`. Is it by choice?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca One should be the active target and the other just the dependency

Comment: `but I don't want to blindy execute make -C src/ from the parent Makefile` => I would do exactly that and let the `src/Makefile` decide if it needs to rebuild anything or everything is up-to-date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82363/discussion-between-nowox-and-eugeniu-rosca).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've asked explicitly for an explanation of what is happening, rather than any help with the problem you're trying to solve, I'll provide the former and ignore the latter.

If you use `make -d` and examine the output you'll quickly see what happens; here's an excerpt:

```
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'src/bar.o'.
     Prerequisite 'src/bar.h' is newer than target 'src/bar.o'.
    No recipe for 'src/bar.o' and no prerequisites actually changed.
    No need to remake target 'src/bar.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'src/exec'.
   Prerequisite 'src/bar.o' is older than target 'src/exec'.
  No need to remake target 'src/exec'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'all'.
```

So, make sees that `bar.h` is newer than `bar.o`, but there is no recipe available to build `bar.o`, so it doesn't do anything with `bar.o`.  As a result, make notes that the timestamp for `bar.o` has not changed, so `bar.o` is not newer than `src/exec`, so `src/exec` is not rebuilt.