# How to tell make to watch dependencies of a sub-make target?

Tags: makefile

I was investigating on the [same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218946/make-does-not-follow-the-dependencies-chain), but I was not very clear of what I was asking, even for myself. Sorry for those who spent time answering my unclear question.

So let's try again with a more realistic example. We consider this structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
└── src/
    ├── bar
    ├── foo
    └── Makefile
```

Where the main Makefile is:

```
all: src/foobar    
src/foobar:
        make -C $(dir $@)
```

And the sub-makefile is:

```
foobar: foo bar
        join $^ > $@
```

If I run make for the first time (from `./`) everything works as expected, `foobar` is produced.

```
$ make
make -C src/
make[1]: Entering directory '/project/src'
join foo bar > foobar
make[1]: Leaving directory '/project/src'

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

However if I touch any of the `foobar` dependencies. The parent `Makefile` will not regenerate the target. Here, I perfectly understand the behavior of Make, but I want to tell it to be aware of `foobar`' dependencies.

```
$ touch src/foo
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

My current solution which is not very neat is to ask for the dependencies. So the `src/Makefile` become:

```
src=foo bar

foobar: $(src)
    @echo "Joining"
    join $^ > $@

files: $(src)
    @echo $^
```

And the `./Makefile`:

```
all: src/foobar

src=$(addprefix src/,$(shell make --no-print-directory -C src files | tr '\n' ' '))

src/foobar: $(src)
    make -C $(dir $@)
```

I must also say that this particular example could be simplified using a single `Makefile` only. My real example is quite more complex. The `src/Makefile` generate an executable while the parent `Makefile` do lots of other things (packing in a specific format, generate the documentation, build other sub-makefiles and so on). Thus, I want to keep these tasks well separated and I need to different `Makefiles`.

Comment: Why do you bother with a sub-makefile in the first place ? Can't the top-level one simply do the job ?

Comment: @Chnossos have you read the last part of my question? I need to have two makefiles because they do a very different job.

Comment: Oops my bad, accidentaly skipped that part

Comment: Maybe forcing the top-level Makefile to call the sub-level one would be enough instead ?

Comment: Do you mean with [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html) kind of solution?

Comment: Yes. This way the top-level Makefile doesn't bother about the dependencies or the target really, it delegates all of this to the sub-level Makefile.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case I am afraid that everything that depends on this target will be also rebuilt. I have to test it by the way.

Comment: Why should it happen ? The sub-level Makefile will control that the target is rebuilt only if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main `Makefile` create a dependency for the child target or directory that is always in need of building, and let the child Make then do the real work.

There is a good example here: http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/slides/make/slides/makerecurs.html.

To translate for your case, change your main `Makefile` to be:

```
all: src/foobar

src/foobar: force
    $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) -C src

force:
    true
```

I also added `$(MFLAGS)` which will pass same flags from parent to child `make`.

Comment: You could also just set `src/foobar` to be a `.PHONY` target, like [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).